# How to refactor this code to search through multiple properties of a BindingList?

Tags: c#, search, filter, textbox, bindinglist

I have created a Search button and an associated texbox in Windows Forms to search through a DataGridView. The DGV shows information in a BindingList. The BindingList has the properties PartID, Name, Price, Instock, Min and Max which are of the types int, string, decimal, int, int and int. I can get the search to function properly but the code itself looks clunky. How can I make my 'for' loop search through the BindingList with less code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.AllParts.Count; i++)
{
    //I would like to condense this if statement into one line of code
    if (Inventory.AllParts[i].PartID.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString())
        || Inventory.AllParts[i].Name.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString())
        || Inventory.AllParts[i].Price.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString())
        || Inventory.AllParts[i].Instock.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString())
        || Inventory.AllParts[i].Min.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString())
        || Inventory.AllParts[i].Max.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text.ToString()))
    {
        dgvParts.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the "BindList" uses a collection of classes for the data, why not search that collection?  The class could offer up a composite searchable string that you test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example refactor like this:

```
bool CheckOR(Func<string, bool> predicate, params object[] values)
{
  //if ( predicate == null ) return false;
  foreach ( object value in values )
    if ( predicate(value.ToString()) )
      return true;
  return false;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < Inventory.AllParts.Count; i++ )
{
  if ( CheckOR(s => s.Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text)
               Inventory.AllParts[i].PartID,
               Inventory.AllParts[i].Name,
               Inventory.AllParts[i].Price,
               Inventory.AllParts[i].Instock,
               Inventory.AllParts[i].Min,
               Inventory.AllParts[i].Max) )
  {
    dgvParts.Rows[i].Selected = true;
    found = true;
  }
}
```

Using Linq:

```
bool CheckOR(Func<string, bool> predicate, params object[] values)
{
  return values.Any(v => predicate(v.ToString()));
}
```

Simplified to:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < Inventory.AllParts.Count; i++ )
{
  var values = new object[]
  {
    Inventory.AllParts[i].PartID,
    Inventory.AllParts[i].Name,
    Inventory.AllParts[i].Price,
    Inventory.AllParts[i].Instock,
    Inventory.AllParts[i].Min,
    Inventory.AllParts[i].Max
  };
  if ( values.Any(v => v.ToString().Contains(partsSearchTextBox.Text)) )
  {
    dgvParts.Rows[i].Selected = true;
    found = true;
  }
}
```

More detail is needed to further improve in case it is possible, and maybe reflection can be used because if all fields are checked we can parse properties. Or a predefined array with names of properties could be used.

Also you can use filters using this [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView) that works fine and great.

There is [BindingSource.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter), but it does not work on the standard `BindingList`.

*Related questions*

[Applying a filter to a BindingSource, but it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725674/applying-a-filter-to-a-bindingsource-but-it-doesnt-work)

[Filter BindingSource when DataSource is a BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560365/filter-bindingsource-when-datasource-is-a-bindinglist)

[DataGridView Filter a BindingSource with a List of object as DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074032/datagridview-filter-a-bindingsource-with-a-list-of-object-as-datasource)

[Filtering BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746869/filtering-bindinglist)

[Filtering BindingSource and DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560310/filtering-bindingsource-and-datagridview)

[C# filter objects with BindingSource in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797956/c-sharp-filter-objects-with-bindingsource-in-datagridview)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't familiar with LinQ or refractoring.

Comment: [Linq 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) | [Linq 2](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/linq) | [LINQ (MSDocs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) | [Deferred Execution of LINQ Query](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution) | [Deferred Vs Immediate Query Execution in LINQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-in-linq/) | [Deferred execution and lazy evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation)